# jQuery sortable error when trying to update the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery sortable to allow users to be able to sort which order images show up. However I am having trouble sending the actual order to the php script

JS:

```
$( ".sort-p-images" ).sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui){
        var form_data = { order: $(".sort-p-images").sortable('toArray')) }
        $.ajax({
            url: "update_img_order",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(json)
            {
                console.log('ajax done');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The error I am getting is:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Why can't I include that under the variable `form_data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the excess parenthesis:

`var form_data = { order: $(".sort-p-images").sortable('toArray')) }`

Change it to:

`var form_data = {order: $(".sort-p-images").sortable('toArray')};`